# jQueryMobile - conditionally allow hash if "page" exists?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I saw a lot of related questions, but none that directly have this issue...

I have a very large site for which I am building a jquery mobile theme. I don't have much control over the content though, and when it was built for desktop, a lot of #anchor tags were used to move to positions on the page.

I have fixed this for links on the same page with the following (jqm is a stand-in for the jquery object, I need to clean up the $/jqm references...

This is bound into the mobileinit event, and works if there are anchors on the page:

```
jqm('div').live('pagebeforecreate', function(e, data)
{   
    if(location.hash.length>0){
        if($(location.hash).length>0){
            if ($(location.hash).attr("data-role") != "page")
            {
                    $.scrollTo(location.hash, 800);
            };
        }
    }
    //Check to see if there are any internal links on page
    $("a[href*='#']").each(function()
    { 
    //make sure they aren't legit jqm pages
        if($(this.hash).length){
            if ($(this.hash).attr("data-role") != "page")
            {
                //Disable jqm behavior, instead scroll down the page
                $(this).click(function(event)
                {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                    $.scrollTo(this.hash, 800);
                    return false;
                });
            };
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('data-ajax','false');
        }
    });
});
});
```

So, if a user is on foo.php, and there's a link to #bar and #baz, it will nicely scroll to them, knowing that they aren't data-role="page"

But if the user is on foo.php and there's a link on that page to qux.php#bar it chokes because when the page loads, it is trying to to a changePage to #bar, but #bar on qux.php is really just an id for a regular old div.

It seems to me that something like the on-page solution above would work for this as well, but maybe I would need to bind to the actual page load instead of the pagebeforecreate?